# recursive reading for files in folder using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a program which is not checking the file update time but its not checking recursive folder files.kindly help for recursive folder files as well.
My code is here :

Sub getfilestat1()
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim CurrCyleTime As Date
    Dim PrevCycleTime As Date
    Dim DBCycleTime As Date

```
Dim connectionString As String, sql As String
Dim _SQLConnection As AseConnection
Dim _SQLCommand As AseCommand
Dim _SQLAdapter As AseDataAdapter
Dim _DataSet As DataSet
Dim _SQLReader As AseDataReader


_SQLConnection = New AseConnection
_SQLCommand = New AseCommand
_SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source='10.49.196.97';Port=9713;Database=db_print;Uid=kuat199;Pwd=testing1; "
_SQLCommand.Connection = _SQLConnection
_SQLCommand.CommandText = ""
_SQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
_SQLCommand.CommandTimeout = 900000000


_SQLConnection.Open()


Dim command As New AseCommand("select * from Kampachi_Cycle", _SQLConnection)
Dim reader As AseDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()

    ' Console.WriteLine(reader("pol_no").ToString() & " " & Convert.ToString(reader("image_return")) & " " & Convert.ToString(reader("no_of_images")))
    DBCycleTime = reader("CYCLE").ToString()
End While
' Dim asSettings As AppSettingsSection = cAppConfig.AppSettings

'Dim fi As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\Vimal\test")
Dim fi As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("\\kaip3r7ciwf01\BicorData\report\kam\")
Dim files = fi.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()


'For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(Directory, "*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
'For Each file In files Select file Order By file.CreationTime Descending
''Dim first = (From file In files Select file Order By file.CreationTime Ascending).FirstOrDefault



'Count the number files in network path
Dim fcount = files.Count()

'Fetching the previous cycle run time from config  file
PrevCycleTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PrevCycleTime")
CurrCyleTime = Now()
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PrevCycleTime") = CurrCyleTime

''''My.Settings.Save()
For i As Integer = 0 To fcount - 1
    If files(i).LastWriteTime > DBCycleTime.AddMinutes(-20) Then
        fileName = files(i).Name.ToString()
        Dim insertCmd As New AseCommand("INSERT INTO Kampachi_FilesProcess " + " ( FILENAME, FileReadStatus) " + " VALUES( @file_name, @read_stat )", _SQLConnection)
        Dim parm As New AseParameter("@file_name", AseDbType.VarChar, 1000)
        insertCmd.Parameters.Add(parm)
        parm = New AseParameter("@read_stat", AseDbType.VarChar, 12)
        insertCmd.Parameters.Add(parm)
        Dim recordsAffected As Integer
        insertCmd.Parameters(0).Value = fileName
        insertCmd.Parameters(1).Value = "Y"
        recordsAffected = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If i = 0 Then
            fileName = files(i).Name.ToString()
            Dim updCmd As New AseCommand("update Kampachi_Cycle set CYCLE = Getdate()", _SQLConnection)
            Dim updparm As New AseParameter("@file_name", AseDbType.VarChar, 1000)
            recordsAffected = updCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If


    End If


Next
```

End Sub

After these changes it looks fine and giving out properly.
It is giving recursive reading as well.

Comment: What part of your code do you think should be recursive?

Comment: @Enigmativity part which read the files inside folder.it cannt read subfolders files.      Dim files = fi.GetFileSystemInfos.ToList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Dim files = fi.GetFileSystemInfos.ToList()
```

To:

```
Dim files = fi.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
```

---

To answer below question about the `If` not checking all of the files: You are correct, but your code explicitly used the `FirstOrDefault` method so it would only ever examine the first file. I don't know what you're doing with the rest of your program here, and your question didn't specify, but the above answered your question about recursive file searching.

To get a list of all the files that are older than 25 minutes use this code:

```
Dim files As List(Of FileInfo) = fi.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList
Dim oldFileTimeStamp As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-25)
Dim olderFiles As List(Of FileInfo) = files.Where(Function(fi2) fi2.LastWriteTime > oldFileTimeStamp).ToList()
```

Please, if this answered this *specific* question, please click the accepted answer button. If you have additional questions, unrelated to the original question, please open a new Stackoverflow question, and do not add new questions to an existing Stackoverflow question. This makes it easier for future viewers to find answers to your follow up question(s) (ie: search won't find questions inside of question, it only finds the original question).

Comment: thanks for you reply , it works for give all the iterative .But i just need to iterate if case for each file                                                                                                                                                                      If first.LastWriteTime > Now.AddMinutes(-25) Then
    ' fileName = File.
    MsgBox(Now.AddMinutes(-25))
    fileName = first.ToString()
    'PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.stoplight_red
Else
    'PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.stoplight_green
End If

Comment: @vim - I don't follow. You already have code that tests if a file's `LastWriteTime` is older than 25 minutes. With the change I supplied you would get all of the files in that folder structure. You can then filter over that list finding these older files as you need. I'm not sure what you are trying to iterate over.

Comment: actually "If" condition will not check all the files timing.i need to "For" loop to check all the files timing.but with this code I dint able to put "for" loop before if condition. if I am able to put a "For" loop before "if" condition that check time for all files then my issue will resolve. i tried but not working.